# Working with One-to-One unidirectional relationship in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity named Install that has two properties: a hostname and a service call number.  The service call number is optional.  Rather than allow the field to be null and violate 1NF, I created a second entity called ServiceCall that has a one-to-one unidirectional relationship to the Install entity.  My problem is that when I enter both a hostname and a service call into the form and submit, only the hostname is persisted, not the service call and the relationship.  Here is my code:

Service Call Entity

```
class ServiceCall
{
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $serviceCall;

private $install;

// Getters / Setters
}
```

Install Entity

```
class Install
{
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $hostname;

private $serviceCall;

// Getters / Setters
}
```

Relationship config:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Install:
type: entity
table: null
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    hostname:
        type: string
        length: 255
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }

AppBundle\Entity\ServiceCall:
type: entity
table: null
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    serviceCall:
        type: integer
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
oneToOne:
    install:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Install
        joinColumn:
            name: install_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

Controller method:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Install();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('install_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Install:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Install Form type

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('hostname')
        ->add('serviceCall', new ServiceCallType())
    ;
}
```

ServiceCall Form Type

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('serviceCall')
    ;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the ServiceCallType form too?

Comment: Added the buildForm method from ServiceCallType.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add OneToOne relation for Install entry,  not for ServiceCall entity.

And not forgot add cascade persist options for relation.

And also need create new ServiceCall entity for relation.

For this  use DataTransformer in ServiceCallFormType

Comment: Thank you! Data transformers is the answer to so many things I've been trying to do with this project!